# Use Dropdown selection to call specific action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, for-loop, dropdown

I have a `has_many` through association for three models. One model has individual tests that can be administered. The second model is the name of a group of those tests. (The group name of triathlon will have associations to multiple records in the individual test model).

- I want the user to be able to select a group name from a Dropdown
- and when they do it passes a param to a specific action in a controller that then is tested through the association model.

I can get the form to look correctly, but not pass parameters to a specific action and then return to the same page.

I have searched and tried for hours to no avail. What’s the correct Cr form_for syntax (or something entirely different.)

Below is my current code

```
<% form_for @labwork, :url => {:action => "groupcreate"} do |f| %>

<%= f.form_group :lab_id, class: 'row' do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Group", class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
  <div class='col-12 col-md-10'>
    <%= f.collection_select :lab_id, Labgroup.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a lab group "}, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <div class="d-flex">
<div class="ml-auto">
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", labworks_path, class: 'btn btn-outline-default' %>
</div>
```

I also have a def creategroup in my labworks controller.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: you should try and get a little more specific ... what param is not getting passed to the controller? How are you attempting to read the param inn the controller?